# What is the difference between TFHub and Model Garden?

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model, tensorflow-hub

[TensorFlow Hub](https://tfhub.dev/) is a repository for pre-trained models. [Model Garden](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) (Model Zoo) also keeps SOTA models and provides facilities for downloading and leveraging its models like TfHub, and both of them are created by TensorFlow.

Why did `Tensorflow` make two concepts for a model repository?

When should we use TfHub for retrieving a well-known model, and when should we use Model Garden to download a model? What is the difference between them?

Comment: We mostly expect users of TF Hub to treat models as blackboxes with clearly defined inputs and outputs. If a model meets your needs (eg. accuracy, speed, size, pre-training category), then use it! If you instead want to dig into the internal details of a model's structure, then you may be more interested in code-first resources, such as Model Garden or Keras applications. These often come with pre-trained checkpoints that can be loaded with the provided code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TF Hub provides **trained models** in SavedModel, TFLite, or TF.js format. These artifacts can be used for inference and some can be used in code for fine-tuning. TF Hub does not provide modeling library code to train your own models from scratch.

Model Garden is a **modeling library** for training BERT, image classification models, and more. Model Garden provides code for training your own models from scratch as well as some checkpoints to start from.